# Is there a way to export 3D objects with animation from Blender or any other app into OpenGL ES 1.1 code?

Tags: opengl-es

The problem is that all the examples I've found are obsolete or iOS/Android specific and not "pure" OpenGL ES 1.1.

If anyone can provide me with a good example/tutorial/book it would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Aren't models first parsed and then rendered with a programm interacting with opengl? i have never heard about opengl having an format like .x (directX) that can be rendered "automatically".